# Request to url with referrer

Tags: php

How can I send request to a URL:
 http://www.flashi.tv/embed.php?v=HitSportsNet41125 
on port 80 with referrer http://sportsembed.com/stream-1.php 
to crawl the source code?

Can I use cURL in PHP?

Comment: And it is really easy to find in [the manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html What have you tried? Where is your code? Have you read the manual?

Comment: @EmilVikström And what code could he have provided for such a simple thing (sort of a one line code if you think of it)? Downvoting on stackexchange has gotten very aggressive lately. Maybe it should cost more the more you use it.

Comment: Tiberiu: That discussion should be held at Meta, really, but I disagree with you. The tooltip of the downvote button says this: "This question does not show any research effort", which is *exactly* what I think of this question. See also [Is lack of (other) research a reason to downvote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97880) and [Should downvotes on questions be "free"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90324)

Comment: @emil You didn't answer my question. There is nothing more which he could have provided to help us give a better answer or just answer. I was pointing at your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cURL is an optional module in PHP and you might not find it installed everywhere.

Here's something part of PHP core:

```
$contextOptions=stream_context_create(array(
    "http"=>array(
        "method"=>"GET",
        "header"=>
            "Accept-language: en\r\n".
            "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n".
            "Referer: http://sportsembed.com/stream-1.php\r\n",
        "user_agent"=>"CrawlingBot v1.0"
    )
));
file_get_contents("http://www.flashi.tv/embed.php?v=HitSportsNet41125", /*include path*/ false, $contextOptions);
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (green checkmark under voting buttons).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http:// www.flashi.tv/embed.php?v=HitSportsNet41125');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http:// sportsembed.com/stream-1.php');
$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

I know referrer is spelled incorrectly, it's just something we all have to life with :/

Comment: I actually lifted it from an example within the PHP documentation pages. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Thanks ..I have looked up the guide...Worked it out..with your reference

Answer (score 0):

Yes, curl can do this.

Googling `php curl set referrer` gives some good hints:

- [The PHP manual on curl (search for "referer")](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)
- [Setting the PHP referer with PHP curl](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-http-referer/) which shows this example code:

> ```
> $ch = curl_init();
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/2');
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.example.com/1');
> $html = curl_exec($ch);
> ```